# How to upgrade Magento from 2.3 to 2.4?

Tags: magento2, upgrade

My M2 website is currently on 2.3.1 and I want to upgrade it to 2.4 (Latest). Can anyone provide steps to update it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you talking about magento-2.3.4?